# Group by two column but show more data from the table - payout issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, duplicates

This is part of my questions fixing the payout issue. This one is 4th  and hopefully the last.

I have customers table and I am fetching only about 10 fields from it. The problem is, it contains duplicates. Not the whole row is duplicated but two field that I identify records with contain duplicates (although only a few). These two field are

1. Account_Number
2. Supplier

My test table looks like this

```
id  account_no  supplier   customer_name        meter_no  StartDate    EndDate       EnrollDate    active      account_type usage*   repid 
--- ----------- ---------- -------------------- --------- ------------ ------------- ------------- ----------- ------------ -------- ------
1   1000        MOBIL      photo company        345       11/01/2011   12/01/2011    09/01/2011    active      cat2         2000     100   
2   1000        MOBIL      photo company        145       11/05/2011   12/04/2011    09/15/2011    active      cat3         2000     100   
3   1000        MOBIL      photo company        645       11/05/2010   12/04/2010    08/25/2010    inactive    cat2         1000     100   
4   1001        HESS       Adventure company    485       11/01/2011   12/01/2011    09/01/2011    active      cat2         1500     200   
5   1002        SHELL      School company       678       11/05/2011   12/04/2011    09/15/2011    active      cat2         3000     100   
6   1003        BP         Hospital company     595       11/05/2010   12/04/2010    08/25/2010    inactive    cat2         5000     300
```

Note that account No 1,2 and 3 are duplicates because they have the same Account_no and Supplier. Atthough the rest of the field are different, that means that are not duplicate in true sense. For example all these three account as different meter_number.

Each record is assigned to a rep (last column). Reps are paid based on joining this table with another that comes from outside. We match based on only these two columns Account_no and Supplier. If they match we say good, we have money for you and the rep gets paid. The problem here is when I joined the table, you can see the same account_no and supplier appears twice for some records. Those needs to removed.

So what really the problem is? Well when report is done, we also would like to print data other than account_no and Supplier. This data includes customer_name, start_date, end_date, usage etc. If I group by all the column, it simply does not get rid of the duplicates. What I want to do is group by only two columns and show other data as well. A typical output be like this

```
id  account_no  supplier   customer_name        meter_no  StartDate    EndDate       EnrollDate    active      account_type usage*   repid 
--- ----------- ---------- -------------------- --------- ------------ ------------- ------------- ----------- ------------ -------- ------
1   1000        MOBIL      photo company        345       *            *             *             *           *            4000     100   
4   1001        HESS       Adventure company    485       11/01/2011   12/01/2011    09/01/2011    active      cat2         1500     200   
5   1002        SHELL      School company       678       11/05/2011   12/04/2011    09/15/2011    active      cat2         3000     100   
6   1003        BP         Hospital company     595       11/05/2010   12/04/2010    08/25/2010    inactive    cat2         5000     300
```

The above table is actually going to be my view. It will get rid of all duplicate account_no and supplier, but what happens to other fields, esp if the value for that is not the same in that group? I am ok with one value or another. There is no strict criteria here because these duplicates are going to be very few any how. That * mean any data is fine but it should belong to either one or the other or sum of both records.

An idea way to create this table would be to add an additional column to the above table and that lists the number of records that were found in that group.

If any questions, please ask. Note the important column is the usage, I would like to have sum of the usage for the group. But if not the highest value in group is ok too.

I am not sure if this can be done in SQL query. Probably there will be a way.

Comment: I do not understand the issue, the issue is not a data problem you can pull off all the duplicated records, or what you consider to be duplicate.  You then handle these duplicates on the RS side (reporting services).  You make `account no.` and `supplier` header type groups so that they show up once, and you use the detailed row (in rs) to show the rest of the data `meter_no`, `StartDate`, etc.  Effectively you will have an indented report.  Very simple, just add two column groups and the rest stays the same.

Comment: Can you show the query that you are currently using for the same?

Comment: @JonH that's a great comment. My output is by the way in Excel. The records are just row by row. There is no detail view. Your approach is similar to what crystal Reports do, but I am using SQL and I do not know how to do the detail view.

Comment: This is old query that goes like this `select A.col1,A.col2,A.col3,..,B.col1,B.col from A join B on account_no and Supplier group by A.col1,A.Col2,A.co3,...,B.Col1,B.col3` as you can see all the fields that are fetched we are grouping by it (and there is no other way). This does not effectively removes the duplicates for us.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter My comment was in regards to how to do it in SQL Reporting services, I am not talking about crystal reports at all (In fact I despise crystal reports).  What you are talking about is very common for reporting services.  I do it all the time and would meet your needs perfectly.

Comment: @JonH I have no idea what a reporting service is in SQL :(, have to find out. Our current reports come from an SQL query that is integrated in our application. It output is an Excel file. If reporting service can be used for this, that will be terrific.

Comment: ahh I thought I read a tag that said reporting services.  My bad scratch what I said, thought you were using reproting services from ms.

Comment: nope. But now at least I know, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ok with one value or the other you can use a Min() or Max() function on the select with the group by and you'll get one or the other.

```
select a, b, min(y), max(z) from table group by a, b
```

Comment: But you do not need to do this on the db server side, this is more of a presentation issue then anything.

Comment: This addresses the problem but Ideally I would like kind of reporting where where it has detailed view of a "group by" fields so we can see individual records in each group.